# Xcode UI dotted separator issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode15, iosdeployment

[image]

There are dotted separators in every line in my Xcode project. I am not sure where these come from.

My Xcode version is 15.0 and I am using Apple M2 Pro with OS Sonoma 14.0. I am also facing indentation issues with my remote repository. Seams like extra spaces added autometically.

Answer (score 1):

You have "Invisibles" enabled in the Xcode editor - This shows invisible characters, such as spaces and carriage returns, with symbols.  The dot is a space.

To hide them, simply turn off the Invisibles option in the Editor menu

[image]